# os.walk Python can't print all drivers

Tags: python, python-3.x, os.walk

Im using os module to get all the files in a directory

> drives = [ chr(x) + ":\" for x in range(65,91) if os.path.exists(chr(x) + ":\") ]
>
> print(drives)

prints out

> ['C:\', 'D:\']

then I look for all the files in those disks with

```
counter = 0
inp = '.png'
thisdir = os.getcwd()
for r, d, f in os.walk(drives[0-1]):
    for file in f:
        filepath = os.path.join(r, file)
        if inp in file:
            counter += 1
            print(os.path.join(r, file))           
print(f"counted {counter} files.")
```

but I get only D:\ drives '.png' file's which print's out 55.000 of pictures location on the drive I cant get c:\ what am I doing here wrong I'm a bit python newbie right now so I don't know what to do can someone help me please?

Comment: `drives[0-1]` is `drives[-1]` which is `'D:\'`... you probably meant to loop over `drives`

Comment: yes how can I loop over all the drivers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reply to your comment, this is how you'd loop over `drive`:

```
counter = 0
inp = '.png'
for drive in drives:
    for r, d, f in os.walk(drive):
        for file in f:
            filepath = os.path.join(r, file)
            if inp in file:
                counter += 1
                print(os.path.join(r, file))           
print(f"counted {counter} files.")
```